# IFFT with WebAudio Analyser

Tags: fft, inverse, web-audio-api, ifft

Is there any way to perform an IFFT using the WebAudio Analyser node?  I notice there is a getByteTimeDomainData method, but how would I feed it magnitude and phase arrays?  Do I connect an AudioBuffer source to it containing interleaved mag and phase values?

Answer (score 3):

Use a PeriodicWave node for IFFT. You can find more information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#PeriodicWave)

Comment: is PeriodicWave node same as the old Wavetable node?

Comment: Thank you. Can you show a short JSFiddle code example of how to use the PeriodicWave node?

Comment: The WebAudio AnalyserNode only seems to support the real part of the Fourier transform? Maybe I'm missing it, but I can't seem to extract the complex phase part from WebAudio's FFT.